# Why are dots invisible?

Tags: owl-carousel

For some reason, the navigation dots on my owlcarousel are invisible. They are rendered and I can find them in the code, but they are not shown.

Can someone figure out why?

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html Could it be the `pagination` option?

Comment: Please refrain from using URL shorteners. This time, they were broken and removed from your post, you can reupdate it with actual data.

Answer (score 2):

You should include `*= require owl.theme` in your `application.css` file. 
It will resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. The source of the problem is `opacity: 0;` property set to .owl-controls and .owl-dots blocks. Change it to something different from 0 then they will appear. They're in theme-fe7522.css.

```
#sns_slideshow_wrapper .owl-controls {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#sns_slideshow_wrapper .owl-controls .owl-dots {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your help! It still hides all dots until hovering over the banner. Is it possible to always show them?

Comment: You've forgot to change `#sns_slideshow_wrapper .owl-controls` opacity to 1. After you've done it everything will be okay) Don't forget to mark the answer if it's correct)